# working out the mean from a csvfile already containing names

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import operator
import csv
question= input("Are you a student or teacher: ")
if question=="student" or "s" or "Student":
   print("You are using the wrong program. Please use the arithmetic quiz")
elif question=="teacher" or "t" or "Teacher":
   print("Hello and welcome to the program which lets you see your students' scores in the arithmetic quizes")
    form=input("What form do you want to view the results of? 1,2 or 3?")
    if form=="1":
       print("if you want the data sorted by names in alphabetical order")
       print("enter 1, if you want the data sorted by scores highest to")
       print("lowest enter 2, if you want the data sorted by average score")
       teachermenu=input("highest to lowest enter 3:")
       if teachermenu=="1":
          start=csv.reader(open("form1.csv"), delimiter=";")
          datasorted= sorted(start, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
          data= open("form1.csv","r")
          for eachline in datasorted:
             eachline.sort()
             print(eachline)
          data.close()
      elif teachermenu=="2":
         data= open("form1.csv")
         start=csv.reader(data)
         for line in start:
            scores = (line[1:5])
            scores.sort(reverse = True)
            print(scores)
      elif teachermenu=="3":
         studentsaverages=[]
         data= open("form1.csv")
         start=csv.reader(data)
         for line in data:
             numbers=(line[2:4])
             numbers=list(map(int, numbers))
             mean= round(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
             data.append(mean)
             data.sort(reverse=True)
             print(studentsaverages)
```

in this code the working out of the mean doesnt work and i dont know why
i have tried several times 
but it doesnt seem to work 
also the other parts of the code work 
but the working out of the mean doesnt 
e.g. putting it highest to lowest works 
and so does putting the names in alphabetical order

Comment: Can you also post what error are you getting? What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\work_bob - Copy.py", line 35, in <module>
    numbers=list(map(int, numbers))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'

Comment: why isnt anyone helping me

Comment: one of your `numbers` has an `S` and is not an a number. Thats whats causing your `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'`. Make sure your `form1.csv` is formatted correctly. Add a `print(numbers)` after `numbers(line[2:4])` to see which line has an `S`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct what you are trying to do, you need to append and then sort the mean to the **studentsaverages** variable(after the for loop) instead of data.
for example:

```
elif teachermenu=="3":
   studentsaverages=[]
   data = open("form1.csv")
   start=csv.reader(data)
   for line in data:
      numbers=(line[2:4])
      numbers=list(map(int, numbers))
      mean = round(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
      studentsaverages.append(mean)
   studentsaverages.sort(reverse=True)
   print(studentsaverages)
```

Comment: it doesnt work it brings up this syntax error                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\work_bob - Copy.py", line 35, in <module>
    numbers=list(map(int, numbers))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'

Comment: It means that you probably have not number value('S') in numbers variable after the line:  numbers=(line[2:4]).

Comment: i dont understand is there a chance of you editing my code to make it work pleaseeee